# Angular ng-click function added dynamically

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

I have a un ordered list whose action is decided dynamically.

Directive

```
 function controller($scope, paymentService, $modal) {
       var vm = this;
       vm.attachFile = attachFile;
       vm.actions = data.actionData;

 function attachFile(title, icon, paymentId) {
    // My code
       }
    }
```

Template:

```
   <ul id="actionDropdownMenu" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li ng-repeat="action in  vm.actions.data.actionList" title="{{    action.tip}}">
                <a href="#" ng-click="{{action.command}}">  @*this doesn't work*@
                    <span class="{{ action.icon }}"></span> {{ action.text}}
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Now in my data
action.command is dynamically filled like

```
 actionList = new List<Action>
                    {
                        new Action()
                        {
                    Command = string.Format("vm.attachFile('{0}', '{1}', {2}) ", tip, icon, id),
                    Icon = icon,
                    Text = text,
                    Tip = tip
                        }
                    };
```

and likewise I have many other functions that get added to list based on business logic.
Now in developer it is showing properly as ng-click="vm.attachFile('test,'test',33) but not invoking the function on click. Interesting thing is if I write same function directly in my template it works. Like

```
  <a href="#" ng-click="vm.attachFile('test,'test',33)>  @*this work*@
```

Comment: Do `ng-click="command()"` and inside `command` function implement the actual logic of what happens (whether it's attach file or something else)

Comment: Yes. In attachFile I have my business logic. Say I open a dialog box.

Comment: You want to assign dynamic handler to `ng-click` right? Sometimes it's `attachFile`, other times it's something else. Is this what you need? I'm saying that you should create a generic handler and within it handle all the logic of invoking the actual handler

Comment: That is one way. But then is there a way to pass angular value in function parameter. Say like ng-click ="vm.attachFile('{{ attach.text}}','test',3);. Tough I tried like this in developer it shows values and function is invoked but the first parameter is valued as "{{ attach.text }}" :(

Comment: I got this one  ng-click ="vm.attachFile(attach.text,'test',3) and it works. :) But still if there could be a way to get dynamic handler on ng-click!!

Comment: how many commands/functions do have ?

Comment: So I'm assuming that you have different handlers for different iterations of your `ng-repeat`, correct? What does the different handler depend on? Index?

Comment: I have 10 functions. and they are independent to each other. They have different parameter and action and return values.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom click directive, that can take a string as input and use that as a key accessor to an object that stores your functions to call. Call it something like commandList. you can than attach that list to the scope and call it in the link function. Not the best explanation so here is some code and a working plunk

```
//js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.actions = [

    {
      text: "I speak to an alert boxy",
      command: "speak"
    },

     {
      text: "I whisper to the console",
      command: "whisper"
    },  

     {
      text: "I bring color",
      command: "color"
    }, 


  ];


});

app.directive('customClick', function(){

  return{

    link: function(scope, el, attrs){

      var fn = attrs['customClick'];

      el.on('click', function(){

         scope.commandList[fn]();

      });
    },
     controller : function($scope){



       var commandList = {};


       commandList.speak = function(){

         alert("Hello")
       };


       commandList.whisper = function(){

        console.log("Hello")
       };


       commandList.color = function(){
          document.body.style.background = "LightSkyBlue";
       };

       $scope.commandList = commandList;

     }

  }

})

// html
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <h2>custom  click on single elements</h2>

    <button class ="btn btn-info" custom-click="speak">speak</button>
    <hr />
    <button class= "btn btn-primary" custom-click="whisper">whisper</button>
      <hr />
    <button class= "btn btn-default" custom-click="color">Color</button>
    <br /> <br /><br /> <br /><br /> <br />

   <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading">Custom click in ng-repeat</div>  
    <div class="panel-body" ng-repeat = "action in actions" >
      <li custom-click="{{action.command}}" style = "cursor:pointer">{{action.text}}</li>
    </div>
   </div>

  </body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/6DeswChVqEGDw12yGRFL?p=preview